# How to create variables within dataframe in for loop?

Tags: r, variables, for-loop

I have an R dataframe called `mydata` with the counts of people with a certain age and certain height. So *within* the dataframe I have variables `mydata$ageto10` (=the number of people up to ten years of age), `mydata$ageto20` (=the number of people up to twenty years of age), and so on with the ages 35, 42, and 65. Same goes for height (and a couple of other variables).

I want to create new variables which refer to the count of the number of people within the age range 10to25, the age range 25to35, 35to42, and 42to65. So for the first case, I want to do:

```
mydata$age10to25 <- mydata$ageto25 - mydata$ageto10
```

This works, but I want to do this across all ranges, and do the same for height and the other variables. There must be an easier way than copy-pasting this 40 times and changing the variable names manually! :)

I thought it should be something like this:

```
for (i in c("age", "height"))
{
  for (k in c(10,20,35,42, 65))
  {
  assign(paste("mydata$", i, k, "to", <<next k here>>, sep=""), get(paste("mydata$", i, <<next k here>>, , sep="")) - get(paste("mydata$", i, k, , sep=""))
  }
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work (even if I fill in the k by manually, it seems the `assign` command is not meant for assigning variable names to the current data.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I presume you are a refugee from another statistical package (`stata` perhaps or `SAS`). You can't use assign to assign to columns using `$` and `paste`. In general if you are using `assign` for a standard task, you are doing something that is not idiomatically `R`, or there are better solutions.

something like

```
lower <- c(10,25,35,42)
upper <- c(25,35,42,65)

# create the differences
newData <-   myData[,paste0('ageto',upper)] - myData[, paste0('ageto',lower)]
# name them with valid names (not starting with numbers
names(newData) <- paste0('from',lower,'to',upper)
# add as columns to the original
myData <- cbind(myData, newData)
```

No loops required!

Comment: No way, that's awesome! Thanks! (PS. Yes, refugee from Stata ;-) I'm loving R more and more every day)

Comment: @user1780218 if that solves your problem, you should give the answer a tick!